# Gnosis Safe: signature check fails while calling `execTransaction` from Etherscan

Tags: etherscan, gnosis-safe

I have a 2 of 4 multisig gnosis safe. I have acquired 2 signatures for a transaction. I want to execute the the transaction from Etherscan (making sure I can recover funds in case the gnosis service goes down).

I copy-paste the `data` and concatenate both signatures in the `signatures` parameter while calling `execTransaction` in Etherscan. I set other parameters to zero. However, I get this error: `GS026`

```
require(currentOwner > lastOwner && owners[currentOwner] != address(0) && currentOwner != SENTINEL_OWNERS, "GS026");
```

checking the source code of [GnosisSafe.sol](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L301) most likely `ecrecover` returned 0x0 addy because the signature doesn't match?

[Here's the failed transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x89fdbcef3b41a735c933cbd401454136b8bc939fe25c31714423ba0cc9e833d0). [Here's another one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x76782e5a7d1d26b4d42ef19103e97d52386abb5aa9767dda08d7f961be5bb382) where I switched the order of the signatures. One of the signatures are from the same address I'm using for the execution (0x8e43...). [Here's a succesful txn](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1228326170116e018befc8733e731aebed584db1d19ab5c52e88970a80207aff) I've made from the same addy from the UI.

Is there some trick I'm missing?

Comment: The signatures should be sorted by their signer's addresses ascending. Maybe this is the reason? Also, I think, you need only one signature per address.

Comment: I tried the signature order both ways. Our safe needs 2 signatures and we signed the txn from two different addresses. I'll try to simulate it with tenderly, tryna see the difference

Comment: How do you create the signatures for the safe transaction? Maybe you sign the wrong safeTxHash?

Comment: we created the signatures separately in the desktop app and the web UI. they were correct. I won BTW, I got it thru by finding the payload diff via Tenderly simu. I had to change the "to" parameter to stETH token addy instead of my own receiving wallet addy. Not sure why.